# For a man, does any four-cornered garment require tzitzit?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, men-male

As far as *hilchot tzitzit* are concerned, are there many instances where a Jewish man would be required to affix *tzitzit* to a garment other than a *tallit katan* or *gadol*? A few "for-instances" would include a scarf, (for one who would wear one) a four-cornered head wrap to serve as a head-covering, etc. Also, I remembered reading something like this in *Kitzur Shulchan Aruch*, but at what point does a blanket become a garment? If one were to wrap himself in a blanket and walk around the house (to keep warm, for instance), would the blanket at some point require *tzitzit*?

In the normal course of events, one hardly ever sees a garment which isn't a *tallit* affixed with *tzitzit*, so I'm wondering how far the obligation extends.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5269

Comment: I am amused by the image of a man bringing his brightly-colored snuggie to his rav for inspection.

Comment: Same here :) I'd just like to know what would be required. It'd be hilarious, but it just might be halacha!

Comment: What about a towel? When walking from the shower you might wear it wrapped around yourself.

Comment: It seems to me that the question here would be: "Are these items square, or oblong?"

Answer (score 4):

According to [here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/eng/?id=111):

A blanket does not need tzitzit.

Some say it is because a blanket is a reserved for night use, and the Halacha is that a garment which is meant for use at night is not obligated to have Tzitzit, even if worn during the day.

According to that it would appear that if you had a blanket that you only used during the day, it would require tzitzit.

Others say it has to be worn as a garment in order to be obligated in tzitzit.

Comment: A throw-blanket on a couch is indeed designated for day use (unlike a blanket designated for sleeping at night).

Answer (score 3):

I was told by a rabbi at Ohr Somayach that a "garment", as far as tzitzit is concerned, has to be worn on the body and covering at least the shoulders, so scarves and bandanas don't apply.

Comment: This is true (as per Shulchan Aruch OC 10:10-11), but what about blankets, I wonder?

Comment: Yeah, this is not a complete answer because I can't help with blankets other than by second-hand anecdote.