# should one attach tzitzit to a knitted garment with four corners

Tags: halacha, tzitzis

My question is should one attach tzitzit to a knitted garment with four corners - I understand that one should with a woven garment as explained in [For a man, does any four-cornered garment require tzitzit?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8408/for-a-man-does-any-four-cornered-garment-require-tzitzit)) but is a knitted garment considered as requiring tzitzit as well.

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Usually mens' scarves are not one cubit (about 18 inches) wide, but if yours is, it would need tzitzit

Comment: possible duplicate of [For a man, does any four-cornered garment require tzitzit?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8408/for-a-man-does-any-four-cornered-garment-require-tzitzit)

Comment: well the puzzle for me is that one does not attach tzit ztit to leather garments. the leather is not woven but there seems also an objection to attaching them even if the leather is woven. in a sense my question refers to knitting - is it regarded as woven halachically or not. also how does one determine a corner - with a weave it seems clear but is it clear with knitting?