# Tzitzis on a Scarf

Tags: halacha, clothing, tzitzis

The Shulchan Aruch paskens that one who takes a long, rectangular cloth and wraps it up into a hat-like thing (similar to a turban) does not put tzitzis on it because it's a hat, not clothing ([OC 10:10](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99_%D7%99)). He continues by saying that a handkerchief worn around the neck doesn't get tzitzis (Ibid. :11) because it's used not as clothing but to hold money (MA ad. loc.).

What about scarves? Are they considered like the latter category, or do we say that since they're used for protection and warmth and as a body covering we should put tzitzis on it (provided, of course, that it fulfills the requirements of OC 9)?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8408/2091

Comment: @Lee General vs. specific. That question is much broader than what I'm looking for. I don't know whether community policy calls that a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Aish.com](http://www.aish.com/jl/m/mm/Tzitzit.html) scarfs do not require Tzitzis, because they are less than the minimum size.

> A scarf does not require Tzitzit, because it does not have the minimum
>   size

[Yeshiva.co](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=2813) quoting Tzitz Eliezer also says it is to small as it has to be able to cover the length of a child.

> The reason a scarf does not require Tzitzit is because it is to small.
>   The minimum size is to cover the length of a child. The scarf is also
>   usually worn folded therefore making it all the smaller.

[Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/927994/jewish/Laws-of-Tzitzit.htm) says that it must be a garment for the body and therefore there is no need for Tzitzis.

> In order for a garment to require tzitzit, it must have four corners.
>   It must be a garment for the body and not just the head (such as a
>   shawl) But, unlike an ordinary shirt, the four corners must include
>   two in the front and two in the back

Answer (score 3):

Qizur Shulhan 'Arukh - Yalqut Yosef (Orah Hayim 10:1) [states](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_3.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%99B-B%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99B%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AAB%D7%94%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%90) (my translation):

> צעיף שנותנים על הצואר בימות החורף, אף-על-פי שיש לו ד' כנפות ויש בו שיעור טלית, פטור מציצית. וירא שמים יעשה קרן אחת בעיגול כשיש לצעיף שיעור טלית.
>
> A scarf which one places on ones neck during winter, even though it has four corners and the minimum required size of a tallit, does not require zizit. And one especially fearful of Heaven should make one corner round if the scarf possesses the minimum required size of a tallit.