# Winter Talit - A very cold corona safe minyan

Tags: tzitzis, tallit-gadol

I am currently davening outside with a minyan like most people here in Israel. It is, however, very cold. Is there any reason why there are not talitot are not specially made blankets?

I can see as one potential pitfall that one might confuse the halacha that a blanket, which is not generally used as a garment as its primary function,as cited in [Tzitzis on a Scarf](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79360/tzitzis-on-a-scarf), [For a man, does any four-cornered garment require tzitzit?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8408/for-a-man-does-any-four-cornered-garment-require-tzitzit),
[Garments that unintentionally require tzitzit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/garments-that-unintentionally-require-tzitzit) and similar

I'm very cold and the half open jacket leaves me still pretty cold. הכל בידי שמים חוץ מצינים ופחים - [כתובות ל](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.30a.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Nathan, and welcome (back) to Mi Yodeya! Just to clarify - are you asking why blankets don't have tzitzit? Or why very thick and warm tallitot are not readily available? Or something else?

Comment: It's not so cold. [Could be worse](https://www.sivanrahavmeir.com/the-daily-whatsapp/snow-minyan/).

Comment: @robev Yeah, but we Israelis tend to fall apart whenever it gets too cold, in Israeli terms. Which is why Israel was basically shut down when there was a rare snowstorm about 7 years ago... :D

Comment: @robev thank you for the perspective and laugh

Comment: I'm asking why I don't see this type of garment, I guess why they aren't readily available when they seem much more practical for wearing tefillin than a half open jacket...Obviously I wouldn't take a blanket and tie some tzitzit on it@רבות מחשבות

Comment: @Harel13 listen they turn on the a/c sometimes near me (precorona) during winter

Comment: @Nathan Thanks! To be honest (and halachic discussion aside), I'm not sure I see a huge market for something like that. Who would purchase it, other than those currently davening outdoors due to COVID? Would one be able to make such a product in a cost-effective manner so that they could profit by selling it to the public?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I would argue that in places like Nachlaot, Tzfat, and various Yishuvim there would definitely be a market (not all shuls have heaters). I'm not sure if it could be profitable unless sold as an artistic rendition of a winter תלית or tacked on to an existing company like משכן תכלת

Comment: Why don't you just put on your coat? Most charedim don't expose their arms after having put on the tefillin.

Comment: I would suggest something like a Turkish talles, as they are of much heavier weaves than otherwise common. They are common among chassidim, but should be easily available from your local Mishkan haTchelet or Talitnia retailer

Comment: I  would recommend a vest.

Comment: Wear multiple *taleisim*?

Comment: @Kazi bàcsi how do they do Shema then? I thought you are supposed to touch the tefillin

Comment: By opening your coat for a few minutes?