# Would adding buttons and button holes to a tallis gadol disqualify it?

Tags: halacha, tallit-gadol

I've seen fitted tallisim katanim with buttons connected the front and back for smooth wear.  Could you also add buttons and button holes to a tallis gadol to hellp it stay on?  Or would that disqualify it for the mitzvah?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it would, but +1 for the interesting question. It should be noted that R' Yoel Bin Nun [is known](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11769/5) for wearing a suit jacket with Tzitzith attached (the split in the jacket has been accentuated to make the garment require it).

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11770/connecting-sides-of-tallit-to-avoid-chiyuv-tzitzit

Comment: @DoubleAA So it appears from the link that buttons would not remove its status as a garment needing tzitzis because they are temporary.  I'm curious why no one has ever considered putting buttons on a tallis gadol.  I have one that is too large and it is falling off all of the time.

Comment: Do the buttons change it from a four-cornered garment?  I could use a better description of the placement and function of the buttons.  (A picture would be nice.)

Comment: @Shmuel -- that is the gist of my question. I invision that the button causes the tallis to have either more or less corners, but is not permanent.