# Thin or Thick Strings for tzitzit?

Tags: product-recommendation, tzitzis, tallit-katan

I have worn both thin and thick strings on my talleyot ketanot, however, I will soon need to get new strings, so I wonder which is better, I have heard that thick lasts longer, but I have seen wear on my tallit katan which goes to the contrary. Furthermore, as I wear my tzitziot tucked-in, according to the German minhag, there is no issue of æsthetics.

Comment: [Qiẓur Shulḥan 'Arukh, Yalqut Yosef (Oraḥ Ḥayim 11:8)](http://ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_2.html#סימןBיאB-BדיןBחוטיBהציצית-ח)

Comment: Your edit made me curious :-)

Comment: @Kazibácsi, singular is טלֵית, Mishnaic plural is טליות, which presumably also takes a tzere. Of course, it should be talles, rather than tallet, but I try to keep my transliterations consistent on MY

Comment: I've just looked at Sefaria, and they vowelise it as [טַלִּיּוֹת](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.93a.6), which seems to be something similar to me as ציצית/ציציות. But I've also found the more familiar [טַלִּיתוֹת](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.147a.4) form as well. It seems to me that both might have been in use.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Speaking of consistency, if you are saying talleyot ketanot then tallit would be a feminine noun and should be tallit ketana.  Later on you say tallit katan which means you also believe tallit is a masculine noun and therefore talleyot ketanot is incorrect but should rather be talleyot ketanim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another factor for some people is that thick is a bit easier to tie -- for me, at least.

For those of you who are debating between thin and thick, you can also find medium thickness online. For a long time this was very hard to find outside of Geula (the frum shopping district in Jerusalem), and even there it was a bit scarce: one company was somewhat expensive and the other one was quite close to thin, but labeled medium ("beinoni").

About a month ago Mishkan Hatchelet finally started making medium thickness tzitzit. In fact, they even make it in different lengths (55 cm, 65 cm) and even offer it in a *niputz lishmah* version.

On my webstore we offer medium thickness tzitzit as an option on most of our products, including tallis katan and tallis gadol.

The Shulchan Aruch *poskens* that your tzitzit strings should not be too thin or too thick, but I once asked a rav and he agreed with me that back then tzitzit production was much cruder than it is today, and all tzitzit sold today meet the description of not too thin, not too thick.

Comment: So in other words, if I don't have an issue tying thin, I can do thin, but the reverse is also true. I would be getting the garments (and probably the strings as well) from you. On an unrelated note, how much extra would it cost to have buttons and button-holes on the side of the beged, which has been proven valid elsewhere on this site?

Comment: Noach, I'm not going to quote you prices on a forum, you'd have to contact me directly. But I'm wondering if you could provide me with references to places where it's discussed on Mi Yodaya. I have heard that the producers of tzitzit t-shirts (not undershirts) brought samples to at least two gedolim and they had no problem with it. I once brought one to a local moreh hora'ah and he felt that the Mishneh Berurah would definitely matir snaps. I'm assuming what you have in mind is snaps or buttons along the sides of a standard wool tallis katan. If they are just high up, it's not even a sheilah.

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11785/4504, where he brings the Mishnah Berurah saying effectively that.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer thick tzitzis since they don't rip if they get caught in something like a chair, seatbelt, etc. This has happened to me in the past and sometimes results in having a *pasul* tzitzis.

However, since you wear your tzitzis under your shirt (like the old European minhag) your tztitzis are probably not at risk of getting torn. The thinner tzitzis are a bit less bulky and possibly a bit more comfortable.

Comment: note that I used to have thick strings for the same reason. Then I got one of the strings caught on something and ended up ripping the Begged (I have Chabad Tzitzit, so there are two holes next to each other, with a little space between them. The two holes became one, and all 8 strings came off).

Answer (score 0):

I also preferred thick tzitziot although I wear the tzitzit tucked-in. I still feel comfortable. However, thick tzitzit more often remind me about hashem rather than thins. This is what I felt, I don't know what's the cause even :)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. This doesn't look like an answer. To add additional info to an existing answer, edit it, rather than posting a new answer. When you have 50 rep. you will be able to comment on others' posts. Consider learning more about the site, from this short beginners' guide: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775.