# When and why would one don sackcloth?

Tags: minhag, clothing, mourning-aveilus

There are various instances in tanach of someone donning [sackcloth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sackcloth). I would like to know whether any commentators have compiled an outline as to when and why someone would don sackcloth (is it only for mourning? Do women wear it as well?). I have never seen anyone wear this type of clothing today, is there a reason we no longer do so?

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/garments-that-unintentionally-require-tzitzit/14449#14449

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61895