# When and why did we stop wearing sackcloth?

Tags: minhag, history, clothing, mourning-aveilus, repentance-teshuvah

When and why did we stop wearing sackcloth in times of mourning and other times of distress (e.g., when fasting for rain)?  (I presume sackcloth was quite uncomfortable.)  Sackcloth is mentioned in the Torah in [Bereshis 37:34](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.37.34?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (Yaakov put on sackcloth after getting Joseph's coat of many colors dipped in blood), and is also mentioned in a couple of dozen places in various other Books of the Bible.

(Since writing this, I've heard that in recent past (in memory of the living) when fasts were called in Israel, at least some wore sackcloth.)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33903/759

Comment: Probably it was a thing that everyone used to do, Jews and non Jews, as a sign of mourning. Just the society changed. Just like we don't do a lot of things society used to do. I don't think it was specifically a Jewish custom.

Comment: I take back my previous suggested answer in the comments. Just checked on wikipedia, it was primarily a Jewish thing.

Comment: Bavli Taanit 14b, cf https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9292/759

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is specifically mentioned in the siddur of Rabbi Shabtai of Rashkov for during the time between Rosh HaShanah and Yom Kippur. That means it was being practiced in Poland around 1700-1740. Although not widespread, it is still in practice in some Charedi communities just like kapparot and malkot are still practiced.

Comment: +1 a link or at least exact citation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which charedi communities?

Comment: Here is a link that appeared a few years ago that was promoting the teachings of Rabbi Eliyahu Leon Levy who was niftar this past 4th of Av. Rabbi Levy brought the wearing of sackcloth as part of tikkun chatzot. It was also referenced on his jewishsexuality.com web site which is down now.    https://www.israelnationalnews.com/Blogs/Message.aspx/2224

Comment: Rabbi Levy, z"l was in Bnei Brak.

Comment: Here's another link connected with Breslav that is dealing with how to make the garment and the specific kavannot when wearing it.   http://www.truekabbalah.org/pages/Documents4/k00209.htm

Comment: Here is a link to a news report from the Kotel this past year, 2014. Please note the many photos of men davening in sack cloth. This was from the 17th of Tammuz.     http://www.kooker.co.il/צפו-בגלריה-יהודים-מתאבלים-עם-לבוש-שק-בכ/

Comment: That is very nice, but I actually meant a link to the  siddur of Rabbi Shabtai of Rashkov

Comment: @YaacovDeane  The photo shows people wearing sackcloth over their usual clothing.  That seems to defeat the purpose of wearing something uncomfortable.  (+1 for the link.)

Comment: Yehuda W as explained on the Breslav link, over clothing is optional. It doesn't diminish the mitzvah. Also, in general in this generation the idea of sigufim (physical mortification) is not relevant. That is because it interferes with our ability to serve the Creator with joy.

Comment: mevaqesh to my knowledge, Rabbi Shabbtai's siddur is not on the web. You can purchase a hard copy from many sources.

Comment: As mentioned to you repeatedly, you should include exact references (e.g. page numbers) along with your claims.

Comment: @mevaqesh The siddur has an excellent table of contents which points directly to each subject. Anyone who obtains a copy, from a library of through purchase will have no problem locating the section dealing with sackcloth, malkot and kapparot. The citation is fine.

Comment: "That means it was being practiced in Poland around 1700-1740." It doesn't indicate it was in continuous practice till then. Chasidim, particularly the early ones, are known to have innovated many things.

Comment: @DoubleAA Although your point might have some validity, it is only speculation. If you look at writings from the ascetics among the Rishonim, such things were discussed. It isn't a great leap to think small communities in eastern Europe continued the same behavior.

Comment: FWIW I just looked through the 5626 edition (Lamburg) and I found one line discussing lashes before Mikva (after the Kavanot for eating on Erev YK) and some discussion earlier about Kapparot (something about Gevurah), but nothing about sackcloth. Perhaps editing a page number isn't as stupid as you make it sound. It's possible I just missed it, but as a user I'd rather you give me a page number or something rather than reading through it five more times to check myself.